# Magento 500 errors. First in checkout, now everywhere

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am receiving 500 errors on my Magento webshop.
First the problem occurred only in checkout/onepage and only when logged in (not as guest).
Now every page return a 500 error.

**What I have tried:**

- I have run a magento-cleanup script to reset all file permissions.
- I have checked the magento logs, but no errors present themselves.
- Clearing cache.
- Removing root htaccess.

**Apache error**

Apache error log gives the following message for all 500's:

[:error] [pid 13758:tid 3006368270080] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 2a02:1810:1014:a400:2526:ccb1:97d4:72e6:28829] FastCGI: failed to read from backend server

The website itself gives no errors (php) although I have set all the debug options in index.php.

I have contacted my hoster to check the FastCGI message. But I am thinking the problem remains with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with cooperation from the hoster.
There was a problem with the APC Cache system.

The solution here was to add this to php.ini:

**zend.enable_gc = 0**